# Python to cython - improve performance for iterations over large arrays

Tags: python, performance, cython

I have the following function that use generator to loop over large arrays of coordinates. As performance is really important, I try to convert it to cython.

Is there other change in the cython impletementation that could increase performance? Maybe like declaration of arrays using cpython arrays or else?

**geometry_converter.pyx:**

```
def esriJson_to_CV(geometry, geometry_type):
    def compress_geometry(coords):
        cdef int previous_x, previous_y, current_x, current_y
        iterator = iter(coords)
        previous_x, previous_y = iterator.next()
        yield previous_x
        yield previous_y
        for current_x, current_y in iterator:
            yield previous_x - current_x
            yield previous_y - current_y
            previous_x, previous_y = current_x, current_y

    if geometry_type == "POINT":
        converted_geometry = [int(geometry["x"]), int(geometry["y"])]
    elif geometry_type == "POLYLINE":
        converted_geometry = [list(compress_geometry(path)) for path in geometry["paths"]]
    elif geometry_type == "POLYGON":
        converted_geometry = [list(compress_geometry(ring)) for ring in geometry["rings"]]
    else:
        raise Exception("geometry_converter.esriJSON_to_CV - {} geometry type not supported".format(geometry_type))

    return converted_geometry
```

**benchmark test:**

```
import time
from functools import wraps
import numpy as np
import geometry_converter as gc

def timethis(func):
    '''
    Decorator that reports the execution time.
    '''
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end = time.time()
        print(func.__name__, end-start)
        return result
    return wrapper


def prepare_data(featCount, size):
    """create numpy array with coords and fields"""
    input = []
    for i in xrange(0, featCount):
        polygon = {"rings" : []}
        ys = np.random.uniform(0.0,89.0,size).tolist()
        xs = np.random.uniform(-179.0,179.0,size).tolist()
        polygon["rings"].append(zip(xs,ys))
        input.append(polygon)
    return input

@timethis
def process_data(data):
    output = [gc.esriJson_to_CV(x, "POLYGON") for x in data]
    return output


data = prepare_data(1000, 1000000)
out = process_data(data)
print(out[0][0][0:10])
```

Comment: I'd expect to see Cython implementation and benchmarking numbers in this kind of question.

Comment: Anyone remotely interested in answering such question would like to see a cython implementation. Same goes for actual numbers and measurement method.

Comment: So, you have changed the code in the question to conform to the suggestions on the first answer, but did not comment if you had a better performance on this way.

Comment: added a perf test

Answer (score 1):

Cython is not magic. Cython performance gains are most of the time not really meaningful without making the use of it's static types.

To obtain substantial performance gains, you have to use the cython type declarations.

For instance, instead of doing:

```
x = int()
```

You would do:

```
cdef int x
```

You have a full description of how to use them in the [cython documentation](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/quickstart/cythonize.html).

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, would it be faster if I declare arrays such `converted_geometry` and declare arrays instead of using list comprehension in the if statement?

Comment: @BelowtheRadar If you use cython arrays, yes